# Asset Relationship Object

Tags: standard-objects, asset

At my company we are trying to use the new **Asset Relationship** objects in relation to **Asset**. I have been trying to look for documentation on this new standard object but have not found any. I already know just by observing the object that it is in a Master-Detail relationship with Asset, but that is not enough for me.

1. I would like to know best practices for how and when to use **Asset Relationship**
2. Are there any "gotchas" with **Asset Relationship** that I am not aware of?

Comment: If you can't find any documentation about this object, how did you find out about it? That might provide useful context.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I found out about the object because I was looking at Assets in setup and Asset Relationships was right under Assets

Comment: i'll bet there is pending doc for this as it is clearly available in Setup. But from what I can see it is a way for Assets to be related to other Assets that aren't in the normal Asset Hierarchy. See the `RelationshipType` and `RelatedAsset` fields

Answer (score 2):

> If two assets are related to each other in a non-hierarchical way
>   through a replacement, upgrade, or other circumstance, you can track
>   their relationship in Salesforce using related lists on asset detail
>   pages.
>
> For example, suppose an elevator’s door is tracked as an asset named
>   Door Model 1. Your customer decides to install a newer door, and Door
>   Model 1 is replaced with Door Model 2.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=assets_rel_equal.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

I can't find an Asset Relationship in the Object Reference. However, from the Usages notes in the Object Reference for [Asset](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_asset.htm), the quoted text below may be what you're referring to:

> Use this object to track assets previously sold into customer accounts. With asset tracking, a client application can quickly determine which products were previously sold or are currently installed at a specific account. You can also create hierarchies of assets using the Parent Asset field. An asset hierarchy can contain up to 10,000 assets.